# How to show different rows of same column as two columns in Select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table say 'timekeeper' like

```
id | entry_date 
------------------
1  | 1406864087263
1  | 1406864087268
```

Assume the entry_date column represents in and out time. Instead of put two columns for in and out we used one column. This is wrong design. I accept.

But my requirement is i want select query to produce output like,

```
id | in_time         | out_time
1  | 1406864087263   | 1406864087268
```

i.e., show same column as two columns in select stmt.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My requirement is complex. I minified the the question for understandability. The following link solves my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671168/mysql-select-and-display-two-column

Answer (score 5):

Assumes you always enter before you exit and there is only one enter and exit per id.

```
SELECT id, 
       Min(entry_time) [in_time], 
       Max(entry_time) [out_time] 
FROM   timekeeper 
GROUP  BY id
```

Link to a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a93f5/2

Answer (score 1):

You can create a rownumber with 1 for in_rows and 2 for out_rows and self join the in and out rows

```
with table_with_rows as 
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY entry_date )
    as in_out from timekeeper
)
select in_table.id, in_table.entry_date as in_time, out_table.entry_date
    as out_time from
table_with_rows in_table
inner join
table_with_rows out_table
on in_table.in_out = 1 and out_table.in_out = 2 and in_table.id = out_table.id
```

Link to [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ffd0/6/0)

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LOGINOUT)RNO,ID,LOGINOUT FROM #TEMP

)
SELECT C1.LOGINOUT AS INTIME,C2.LOGINOUT AS OUTTIME FROM CTE C1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE AS C2
ON C1.ID = C2.ID+1
```

Comment: Ive edited your answer to show the code correctly, but it gets a -1 from me for having no description of what youve done to try to answer the OP's question.